# textfields, icon and label in a single line

Tags: javascript, reactjs, textfield

I am using react-reduxm office-fabric-ui. Here is my code:

```
<Icon className="delete-transform-icon" iconName="Delete" />
<Dropdown
   className="modal-value-transform-type-dropdown"
   label={translate("transformTypeLabel")}
   placeHolder={this.state.transform.transformType}                     
   ariaLabel={translate("transformTypeLabel")}
/>
 <br />
<TextField
    className="modal-value-transform-type-TextField"
    label={translate("transformDefaultValue")}
    ariaLabel={translate("transformDefaultValue")}
    placeholder={this.state.transform.defaultValue}
 />
```

it comes in 5 lines.[image]

But I want them in one line like: [image]
How can I do it?

Comment: This is a CSS problem, you should check how to align elements horizontally using CSS.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at solving this problem? How far did you get?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to remove the `br` and use any `GRID LAYOUT` like **bootstrap**, **material-ui** etc. It is much easier to manage elements in columns.
you can do something like this:

```
<div className='row'>
  <div className = 'col-4'></div>
  <div className = 'col-4'></div>
  <div className = 'col-4'></div>
</div>
```

This is just an basic example how you can utilize the power of grid layout. Mostly UI libraries has 12 columns / row grid layout. I hope this would be helpful.

Comment: thanks so much. I used the grid and it solves my problem

Comment: Glad to help you ) you can accept this as answer as well